# How we can limit quadratic function?

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

Consider quadratic function : $f(x) =  Ax^2 + Bx + C$

We Want to obtain $A$ , $B$ and $C$ by inequalities to $f(x)$ passes the first quadrant of Cartesian coordinate  or Second or third or fourth.

How we can obtain range of these coefficients ?

Note : I find an equality to $f(x)$ pass the first quadrant . We know in first quadrant $x > 0$ and $y>0$ . So , we have $A + B + C > 0$ . But I couldn't use this for other quadrants.

Comment: Think about the roots of $f$.

Comment: I was think about roots , but it leads to several conditions . And I want simply way to solve this .

Comment: And I also search for a new solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does have several conditions.

Comment: But for first quadrant , it works.

Comment: I want to know , it is true accidently or we can use it for other quadrants ?